# PHP double login

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication

I have some problem with my LoginForm.When I enter login parameters and click on Submit button
,the username and password field get blank and on again clicking on Submit button without providing parameters it gets login....So we have to click two times on Submit button to login

```
    <?php
     if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
     {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if(!empty($username) && !empty($password))
{
$query = "SELECT id FROM register WHERE username ='$username' AND password='$password'";    
    $query_run = mysql_query($query);
    if($query_run)
    {
        $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);

        if($query_num_rows == 0)
        {
            echo 'Invalid username/password';   
        }
        else if($query_num_rows == 1)
        {
            $user_id = mysql_result($query_run,0,'id');
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
            header('Locaton : index.php');
        }
    }
}
```

}
?>

Comment: This is not a problem, however. Your values of input don't get saved. To fix this just add value attr to the inputs, like this `<input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo $_POST['password']?>">`

Comment: You don't happend to have a empty entry in your database?

Comment: Besides that the mysql_ tags shouldn't be used anymore. Look at Mysqli or PDO.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/327/ I.e. you have a huge security hole: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: FWIW: You should pass full absolute URL (with protocol and domain) as value of `Location` header. Also, it's better to use [domain root](http://tanalin.com/en/blog/2005/12/home-link/) (`/`) as home page URL, not `index.php` — to have one canonical home-page URL.

Comment: @NikolajSvendsen : I do have some entries in database and yes i will use Mysqli or PDO. Thanks for reply buddy

Comment: Here is link to my login files http://www.sendspace.com/file/nd99xu
If anyone can see what is the real problem and correct it.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you have misspelled the header() function

change `header('Locaton : index.php');`

to `header('Location : index.php');`

Comment: Also note that `header()` expects a full (absolute) URL.

Comment: Thanks @Mohd Moe for pointing an error, but it has not helped with the problem

Comment: @PeeHaa : Yea you are right . I must use MySqli or PDO.Thanks